# Return type based on parameter that is key in an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interface:

```js
interface Elements {
   divContainer: HTMLDivElement;
   inputUpload: HTMLInputElement;
}
```

Then I want to make a function like this:

```js
getElement(name: keyof Elements): Elements[name] {
    // Code to get the element.
}

const div = getElement("divContainer"); // returns HTMLDivElement
const input = getElement("inputElement"); // returns HTMLInputElement
```

But it doesn't work, because I can not use the parameter as a type to use as return type. I've played around with `Parameters` already, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) can help here:

```
getElement<T extends keyof Elements>(name: T): Elements[T];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMBRCEAWxFQwB4AVeEADw2uAGd4BrEATxyJ4ZStQwcAfAApUUKgC549AJSKRVGhwDa9ALoBuALAAoE2DwcM8YFgBu8ALyFi6sVIBEN2wGE8GKFioIDDuyvrwAPQR8HAYyDCoXAAS9ACyADIAInauNGYWVoEADshWTkSk5BoYHsWlAKpFEDhQwKHhUTHE8YnwKRkAkqgllaJ5psaBbDCIUGAIueLwAN4m8OtevjQBQTCK-Vk5VWJGxuvwdRiNza37aelDI4unAL5AA)

Comment: Thank you! I could swear I tried it this way and it didn't work, but apparently I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use the parameter as a type to use as return type

So use its type instead:

```
getElement(name: keyof Elements): Elements[typeof name] {
    // Code to get the element.
}
```

Comment: This seems to work as well, although I think it looks weird as `typeof name` just means "string" in this case...

Comment: Not quite. Since `keyof` produces a literal union of `Elements` keys the type of name is not just `string` but (in your case) `"divContainer" | "inputUpload"`. And note that nothing in your code prevents `Elements` keys from being numbers instead of strings.

Comment: You're right, but in that case it still looks like it can be both. With the answer of Aleksey, it's more obvious that it takes the specific entered name to be returned off the Elements.

In any case, both work, I just like the way the other solution looks better :)

Comment: Sure, I'd go with Aleksey's solution as well.