# Returning the strict item-type of an array-property by a given key and an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to provide a helper/wrapper function (`get_item`), which should return a single item of an objects property, but somehow I am unable to get the correct typings done.

```js
// without typings
function get_item(foo, key, index) {
    const array = foo[key];
    // check if the index exists
    if (index in array === false) throw new Error("Item " + index + " not found for " + key);
    return array[index];
}
// usage example 
const item = get_item({bar:[0,1,2]}, 'bar', 0);
```

My attempts seem to fail, as soon as I try to infer the `ArrayItemType` of `array`.

Simply returning the type of `array` by the given `key` is no problem, as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724720/return-type-based-on-parameter-that-is-key-in-an-interface).

But on top of that, I know, that I will only have properties of type `Array`  in my `foo`-object and want to return the type of a single item in the array I selected via the `key`, but that fails, as typescript seems to forget its relation to the `key` property when accessing the array with the index operator.

[Typescript 4.5.4 Playground (same code as below)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhJaB3AhgOwC7Qwe2gcwFMsMALQ6ASw0IFtoUsAHHAZ2spzWgHJK0AJoQAePaFFjQAZgCcc9MhSZymhGRkqFWyaqWhoUtCjwDWhAJ48JcHFOzlorDDICuAYwwuZxqThxWYEGAoKRc0D05uIgwAfWo6AB4oAEgAaQBRAE1oERpBbTNzW2gAMT8AGmTgYGgAIgAvP1roAB86gCMUGVqoAD4ACl8cAC5SiuhC0YzM8qpBEWG0F1p2tQBKFNGAQRkZFHN4GloAFXNVBLKcAG1pgF1e6GroIRoZWn4tewoMM4pilEc-HwABsKIRQUZMNIcDIvtBlDhVOpzLxCmIALwPJYrNQtJwyIFQADeKTcXCcDF2%201GlxuWVu0HR0OuhVuAG4qjUyJRtG50NBVtAdntzAlsasZA8YUKqaL8UCHkJVIIgdAuKiLAFOdA3OQ3CYqHZFHMhMIcsIeRhWClKHZ%20vxTXNKSK1vY5Eh9IQPeldjD%20rVDnQ6tAANQmkSh4NoHBYXxhATQ2HNMOFNZs0nkrDxehMroiq4OkTs5Ilp6Mew8%20E4fgkBw-VSOQh0bS4aCkFAANwoZOBwJQTFYhATrfFuPlaHw5RSJZns6eAh5fJkC4ncKkKA89nLSAoJmjHuNIg3JF%20arsPDz%20zEvlhAPwlC73FMmpS3k8Mm42bZ0G1PrkMmnGcnlOBseHHfBWn0ZYJTEStoywFBWHYfADHaUFsDwetjGFfZAxOX4Lj8OlMnuHgADpxEgWdtRA4xwNg7R4IYJDKBQlA0O%20TDTx4HCDiOWjCOuO5enIqAAF8oCgLCZRFPCBK2AAlBStkyB4mUU5TslyQh8hk-YEn4KQ1AQY50gAWQeAB%20EzzOgUY0EILsZHTSAoBrNR1zcChLmgEkqM6WFtllMVoLUXoXOSRo8CCkUEnA8LxMkyAyTQCkhjssY8CZPzkgC0YrgABnKABGW4pyoqL8tqFBalmWp2lqMrxJc%20diDUd4HN5GFvE3LDtHIbwoBSilRxkOIjjs0bGQIYhxroQZxh4AKeFmYq0yGzNHGcIE5voYZwOm6JdoWnBZh4KKVugNa2SAA)

```js
/**
 * I want to get the item at position 'index' 
 * from the properties with name 'key'
 * of the structure 'Foo'
 */
function get_item<
    KEY extends keyof Foo,  // "zoo" | "bar"
>(foo: Foo, key: KEY, index:number)
    : ArrayItemType<Foo[KEY]> // determines the type of a single element for the property 'key' beeing number|string
{
    const array: Foo[KEY] = foo[key];   // this can be Array<number> or Array<string> depending on 'key'
    // check if the index exists
    if (index in array === false) throw new Error("Item " + index + " not found for " + key);
    const item = array[index];          // at this point the type seems to have collapsed to number|string,
                                        // discarding the fact that we know the exact type of 'array' for a given 'key'
    return item;    // Error
                    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'ArrayItemType<Foo[KEY]>'. 
                    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayItemType<Foo[KEY]>'.
}

type ArrayItemType<ARRAY> = ARRAY extends Array<infer ITEM> ? ITEM : never;

/**
 * Some interface with a few properties of type Array<any>
 */
interface Foo {
    bar : Array<number>;
    zoo : Array<string>;
}

const foo : Foo = {
    bar: [0,1],
    zoo: ["a", "b"],
};
// determines correct types here, this is the way i want it
const number_item :number = get_item(foo, 'bar', 1);
const string_item :string = get_item(foo, 'zoo', 1);
```

Sure adding `as ArrayItemType<Foo[KEY]>` does solve the issue,
but I would like to keep those type castings to a minimum especially when I don't understand why it should not work (which makes me think, that I misinterpret my code somewhere).

So, am I missing something?
Should this somehow not be possible?
Or is the problem with `KEY extends keyof Foo` again, allowing more values than I am aware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhAIBUAsCcHsDuBncBLAZuAbgQwDYCuApuqoQHYAmxGaFxV4IwAUBpQMYAua8F4AObFuASW7EAtuAA8rcOADS4YgA8J1VAAUEAB2KxuAT0XEjAGnlQV64pvAAlYp3iwqMxefCxiuKv3wjcEoAawokCgBtAF0APksFURsNKlQKQkkAIwNLWIAKeEyAKwAuKC8QszLPdGo1MtEASjLISMVoyNFo5LtU4Lq6BiYAfnAGbANwFraOrvAAbysXCmRucFxYWHAAXnBCosjKo2iAbitMcDyAQgBBTdwjADo0ZDvYB7yN2EbG8G44JBjYiIcAAUU2rjyAAMdPB9IYggAiAAk8yOAF9EWN4GsMPBKFQoY0zgplqscAQSDt1ptIvQaKpTucsHljPp4Fg8ERSNteeAAOQE2j0Rj837-BAghgg8EIWDQgBqlNI4Vx+Oo6zW9LU4FR2tU6KJJO8IkIsAEXJIZ3RrFYoAgAFlXKR8HY0HZuGUfNwzSt+jRBoxwHitvQuWgmEdgPrmGxgMBg1xePwhCJxFJZHaEwplGoUto9AZjKYLFmFNY871UE4XG4PF4fH4AkFQuFEFE4pZ4+WkpX7Oksjky-l9i0KlUlF59Q1mlAZp1uotuwpvb69sVDmZosNHnS6oyzt2baxhGIJJI8vNMhsypEAExeAAsXgAbNF0V5+dfYPyvAAGYlwG7AdslgE803PS9v1vB9wGfcA33WVAyW4D8BW-X9wAAk4gITO9bXoCRYAwXBOFIAAxeB4AWKxoLGDJQJiY0AC8qLKVZYHoQQmNYY8UODNjwEo6jdkWBQ6MiP8vAARmiBJwFY+Bb35XBMK-fk5N4s5wLPKQ8jxeBPwwmTAOAhiDB09MLwMz9FMw6TTITDiuMsyD5mgYh8HwJTwEiflEFcfAqA0pDwBQtD+Q8rz4HsxygQmWAvEQNAvL+AFEFtU8rP0qjbKozC7zi5yKEEcBMkINZSJ9AhAniyZsk4XBCGQUg0DWZLUolJBWCAA)

```ts
/** Throws if value is undefined */
function getItem <
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<K, readonly unknown[]>,
  I extends number,
>(obj: T, key: K, index: I): T[K][I] extends undefined ? never : T[K][I] {
  const arr = obj[key];
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) throw new Error(`Property "${key}" not found`);
  const value = arr[index];
  if (typeof value === 'undefined') throw new Error(`Value not found at index ${index}`);
  return value;
}

getItem({bar: [2, 4, 6]}, 'bar', 0); // number
getItem({bar: [2, 4, 6] as const}, 'bar', 0); // 2

interface Foo {
  bar: number[];
  zoo: string[];
}

const foo: Foo = {
  bar: [0, 1],
  zoo: ['a', 'b'],
};

getItem(foo, 'bar', 1); // number
getItem(foo, 'zoo', 1); // string
getItem({hello: ['world'] as const}, 'hello', 1); // never, will throw
```

---

However, beware of the nature of index signatures and arrays in TypeScript:

```ts
getItem(foo, 'zoo', 2); // string but actually never because it will throw
```

- [Typescript: accessing an array element does not account for the possibility of undefined return values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50647399/438273)
- [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess)

Comment: Ah, so I was actually only missing to use a generic index type.
Using `I extends number` and `Foo[KEY][I]` as the return type was all it needed to behave the way i wanted it to.

Though i am still not quite sure as to why that would be necessary.